# Requesting tag [arcpy] be created

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There are not a lot of questions involving the popular GIS/geospatial library ArcPy from Esri ([just 14 at the moment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=arcpy%20is%3Aquestion)), but could someone with the create tags privilege create one for it, please?

If such questions are tagged [arcpy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) then it may entice [ArcPy specialists](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcpy/topusers) from [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com) to visit and help answer them.

Comment: Note that we also already have a [tag:geospatial] tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have gone through the search results you indicate and I have added the [arcpy] tag. Appreciate the pointer.

I have added the tag info as well, copied from StackOverflow.